# VBA Function calling

Tags: excel, function, events, sendmail, vba

I have been working on trying to call a function for a tracker I made in Excel. What I want it to do is email an individual when a cell changes to their name.

I have this code in the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Public Sub sendMail(strTo As String, _
        strSubject As String, _
        strBodyText As String, _
        Optional strCC As String = "", _
        Optional oAttachments As Collection = Nothing)
    'This function creates an email and immediately sends it.

    Dim oMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim persField As Variant

    'Create the email
    Set oMailItem = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    'Populate the email properties
    With oMailItem
        .Subject = "There are OI's for your review"
        If perField = "Name1" Then
            .To = "email1@mail.mil"
        If perField = "Name2" Then
            .To = "email2@mail.mil"
        If perField = "Name3" Then
            .To = "email3@mail.mil"
        .Body = "Good day, <CR> Please review the tracker to see which OIs are ready for your review"
        'Send it!
        .Send
    End With

    'Release the object
    Set oMailItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have always had trouble calling functions and I have this code for the individual sheets:

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target = "$E2:$E17"
    Call SendMail
    End If
End Sub
```

I keep having issues calling the function and have looked. I know I am missing the connection somewhere in the worksheet, but I am at a loss on how to connect it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  No offense, but it's pretty clear that the first thing you need is a beginner's "introduction to VBA" tutorial.  Respectfully, there are a *lot* of nonsense in your question.  Here are a couple recommended tutorials: [Excel VBA For Complete Beginners](http://www.homeandlearn.org/) and also [HomeAndLearn.org Learning VBA](http://www.homeandlearn.org/).

Answer (score 0):

As noted by ashleedawg, there are other errors but to get you going, I believe it should be

```
Call ThisWorkbook.sendMail
```

And you would need to pass the parameters that SendMail expects.